# using Foreign Key value in if condition in Django Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a model that have a  Foreign Key in it. like this:

```
class Chart(models.Model):
     titleFA     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     titleEN     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
```

category related to this model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
     nameEN = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
```

and this is the view file:

```
def drawcharthome(request):
   allcharts = Chart.objects.all()
   allcats = Category.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'charts/drawcharthome.html',{'allcharts': allcharts,'allcats':allcats})
```

I need to check the equality of two parameter in my template:

```
{% for  cat in allcats %}
   {% for  chart in allcharts %}
      {% if chart.category == cat.nameEN %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ chart.api_url }}"> {{ chart.titleFA }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but my inner if do not work!

Comment: I think you are missing another `{% endfor %}` here. Also, you are comparing the `chart.category` (which is an instance of `Category`), with the `cat.nameEN` (the string).

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov I edit the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the related `Chart`s of a `Category` object with `my_category.chart_set`, so you implement this with:

```
def drawcharthome(request):
    allcats = Category.objects.prefetch_related('chart_set')
    return render(request, 'charts/drawcharthome.html',{'allcats':allcats})
```

and render this in the template with:

```
{% for cat in allcats %}
    {% for chart in cat.chart_set.all %}
         <li>
             <a href="{{ chart.api_url }}"> {{ chart.titleFA }}</a>
          </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) is not necessary, but it will load all the related `Chart`s with a single query and do the joining in the Django/Python layer, which will result in two queries instead of *N+1* where you make one query to fetch the `Category`s, and *N* queries to fetch each time the related `chart_set` of a category.

Comment: do you remove the if tag?

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian: yes, because using a double for loop would make the template quadratic in time, which would result in terrible inefficiency, especially when the number of categories and charts grow. Furthermore one should *not* implement business logic in the template, but in the view. Here we simply use `.chart_set.all` to get the *related* objects.

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian: in other words, `cat.chart_set.all` already gives you the filtered set of `Cart`s, there is no reason to pass these to the template, nor to filter this. Especially since the template render engine is not very efficient in the first place.